# PHP error on WordPress site for YouTube embed

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube, embed

In WordPress I'm using the same YouTube embed code that I always have but now it's returning and error of Undefined offset: 1 - I noted the line it applies too in the code.

```
function embed_youtube_video($post_id) {
    $share_url = get_field('share_url');
    preg_match('/youtu\.be\/(.+)$/', $share_url, $matches);
    // the next line throws the error
    if( $matches[1]) { 
        return '<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $matches[1] . '?rel=0&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    } else {
        return false;   
    }
}
```

Now I'm not a PHP expert and stole this code from and old site so I've probably done something super easy to fix and just not spotting it. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the error you get, and in which line is it?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because there was no matches and therefore `$matches[1]` does not exist.

To keep the flow of your code the same change the line to:

```
if(isset($matches[1])) {
```

I should mention, [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/isset) checks to see if a variable is defined. In this case we check to ensure that `$matches[1]` is defined. It's accomplishing the same task as your existing line without throwing an error because `isset()` is immune to undefined errors because the nature of it's function.

Comment: Thanks man, sorry I'm so late getting back to you but this set me up nicely!